# mysql query left join with newest date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the id from first table, and the information in the second table but only if there is any related row in second table, AND where the greatest date of the related rows is smaller(earlier) than time right now...

This is what I have right now:

```
"SELECT t1.id as actID, t2.id AS eventsid, t2.controlled FROM `activites` t1
 LEFT JOIN `events` t2 ON t2.activitesid = t1.id 
WHERE t2.datum < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() GROUP BY t2.controlled"
```

And what I have been trying is something like

```
"SELECT t1.id as actID, t2.id AS eventsid, t2.controlled FROM `activites` t1
 LEFT JOIN `events` t2 ON t2.activitesid = t1.id 
WHERE (SELECT `datum` FROM `events` t3 WHERE t3.controlled = t2.controlled ORDER BY `datum` DESC LIMIT 1) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() GROUP BY t2.controlled"
```

Is there anybody who can point me in wich direction to go or how to type this kind of query?

> There is no need pointing out that I should use PDO, mysqli etc...

Comment: add some table schema and some sample data --- it'll make life easier

Comment: This is probably the single most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag on SO (well, a variation of). Sometimes, it's correctly answered too.

Comment: @Strawberry Is it? I have been googling as an idiot.  I dont find how I can use the "select controlled" into the subquerys WHERE?  because I gues that what I need to do?

Comment: Well, the manual has an article on rows holding the groupwise max, and there are lots of examples of using both corellated and *uncorellated* subqueries (or exclusion joins) both here and elsewhere. But if after all that you're still struggling then pala's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Without a table schema this is difficult to picture based on the information provided.  But why won't this work?

SELECT t1.id, t2.*
FROM `activites` t1
LEFT JOIN `events` ON t2.activesid = t1.id
WHERE t2.datum < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();